# Docker on Raspberry Pi 2: Could not reach any registry endpoint

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, docker

I installed docker on my Raspberry Pi 2 and want to pull some images. But when I try to pull with docker pull nginx, I get Could not reach any registry endpoint. My network connection is ok and even docker search nginx echos all images. I installed docker from the raspbian repository with sudo apt-get install docker.io so it is an older version. I wasn't able to install a newer version. The docker version is 1.3.3.

Also asked in:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38286313/docker-on-raspberry-pi-2-could-not-reach-any-registry-endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current Docker hub does not yet support multiple architecture for an image. So the image you are trying to pull when doing `docker pull nginx` is the x86_64 one and it won't run on Raspberry Pi.

**Update**: Docker has now multiarch support. So many images now can be pulled on both x86_64 and armhf (e.g. `docker pull debian` will work on your desktop/laptop Intel/AMD CPU as well as on your Raspberry Pis). Some images are still not multiarch, for those you can check this Docker repository for images for your specific architecture: https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#architectures-other-than-amd64

For other specific ARM7 images, you can use 3rd parties. But you need to *trust* the authors of these images and many are still experimental. Here are 2 links with what I think are "quality" images:

- https://hub.docker.com/u/armhf/ (old and I suspect no longer maintained)
- https://hub.docker.com/u/hypriot/

But do not trust me blindly :-). Look online at resources for Docker on Raspberry Pi and make up your mind.